# jquery add each <td> an attribute based on another <td> value in the same row

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell, attr

I have a dynamic table based on a python dataframe and I added to the 2nd and 23rd column the following classes:

```
 $(".tablafiltros tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass('ColNodo');
 $(".tablafiltros tbody tr td:nth-child(23)").addClass('ColGest');
```

I have also assigned to .ColGest the following attr:

```
        $(".ColGest").attr("data-pk","index")
```

By this way I am adding the same fixed attribute "data-pk" = "index" to every  in ".ColGest", but what I need is to assign to each ".ColGest"  an attribute that is the content of the .ColNodo  (the cell value)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, is this issue solve ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Loop over all .ColGest items
$('.ColGest').each(function(index) {

   // get the ColNodo cell with same index as the current ColGest in the loop
   const colNodoValue = $('.ColNodo')[index].text();

   // add a data-value attribute with the colNodo value
   $(this).attr("data-value", colNodoValue);

});
```